# When adding D3 script to HTML file DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object Window]' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm using a free HTML template for my site, and when I add the D3 script, the page never loads and I get the above error.  I have tried adding the script as well as downloading the code and referencing it locally.  Once I remove or comment out D3, the page loads perfectly.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Here is the code from the index file starting at the line referenced by the error.

```
// Everything is loaded including images.
    $(window).on("load", function(){

        // Render the page on modern browser only.
        if(renderPage) {
            // Remove loader
            $('body').addClass('loaded');

            // Page transition
            var allPages = $(".tm-section");

            // Handle click of "Continue", which changes to next page
            // The link contains data-nav-link attribute, which holds the nav item ID
            // Nav item ID is then used to access and trigger click on the corresponding nav item
            var linkToAnotherPage = $("a.tm-btn[data-nav-link]");
            
            if(linkToAnotherPage != null) {
                
                linkToAnotherPage.on("click", function(){
                    var navItemToHighlight = linkToAnotherPage.data("navLink");
                    $("a" + navItemToHighlight).click();
                });
            }
            
            // Hide all pages
            allPages.hide();

            $("#tm-section-1").fadeIn();

            // Set up background first page
            var bgImg = $("#tmNavLink1").data("bgImg");
            
            $.backstretch("img/" + bgImg, {fade: 500});

            // Setup Carousel, Nav, and Nav Toggle
            setupCarousel();
            setupNav();
            setupNavToggle();
            setupFooter();

            // Resize Carousel upon window resize
            $(window).resize(function() {
                setupCarousel();
                setupFooter();
            });
        }           
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Are the error messages missing in your description? I don't see any.

Comment: If the quoted error message is really referring to the line starting with `$(window)` - then this probably indicates, that `$` is not the actual jQuery object any more, but has been overwritten by something else. (I tried to check the ds3 docs, to see if it uses `$` as well, but could not find anything saying that at a glance.) Try and run jQuery in non-conflict mode (and keep in mind, that entails replacing the `$` in your code with `jQuery`), and see if that changes anything. If not, then we need a better presentation of the problem - provide a proper [mre] then please.

Comment: @PIG208 sorry the error message is in the title.